# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un Ajax (Array) a un PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Logro capturar de mi formulario y demás en un Ajax, primero intente manejarlo como un array formal y mandarlo por FormData, pero no logro recibirlos de lado de mi PHP, intente manejaron como un Json, pero el problema creo que es al momento de mandarlos o recibirlos.

**IMAGEN DE MI FORMULARIO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MI AJAX ESTA CAPTURANDO LOS DATOS LOS NAMES DE LOS ELEMETOS DE MI TABLA**

```
function registrardetalle(celular)
{
    var parametro2 = document.getElementsByName("parametro[]");
    var cantIn2 =  document.getElementsByName("cantIn[]");
    var precio2 = document.getElementsByName("precio[]");
    var subtotal2 = document.getElementsByName("subtotal[]");
    var determinacion2 = document.getElementsByName("determinacion[]");

    var parametro = [];
    var cantIn = [];
    var precio = [];
    var subtotal = [];
    var determinacion = [];
    var json= []

    for (var i = 0; i < determinacion2.length; i++) {
        parametro.push(parametro2[i].value); //["parametro 1", "parametro 2"]
        cantIn.push(cantIn2[i].value); // [1, 2]
        precio.push(precio2[i].value); //[15, 15]
        subtotal.push(subtotal2[i].value); // [15, 30]
        determinacion.push(determinacion2[i].value); //["determinacion 1", "determinacion 2"]
      }
      celular= JSON.stringify(celular);
      parametro = JSON.stringify(parametro);
      cantIn = JSON.stringify(cantIn);
      precio = JSON.stringify(precio);
      subtotal = JSON.stringify(subtotal);
      determinacion = JSON.stringify(determinacion);

    // INTENTE EL FORM DATA, PERO TAMPOCO FUNCIONO
    // var formData2 = new FormData();
    //     formData2.append('celular',celular);
    //     formData2.append('parametro',parametro);
    //     formData2.append('cantIn',cantIn);
    //     formData2.append('precio',precio);
    //     formData2.append('subtotal',subtotal);
    //     formData2.append('determinacion',determinacion);

        $.ajax({
            url:'../Modelo/registrar_detallecot.php',
            type:'POST',
            data: [{celular: celular, parametro: parametro, cantIn: cantIn, precio :precio, subtotal :subtotal, determinacion:determinacion }] ,
            //data: formData2,
            contentType: "json",
            processData:false,
            success: function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    alertify.success("correcto Detalle!");
    
                }else{
                    alertify.error("Fallo Detalle:(" + r);
                    console.log(r);
                }
                setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);
            }
        });
}
```

**MIS DATOS SE VEN ASI AL INSPECCIONAR EL ELEMENTO EN EL NAVEGADOR:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MI PHP PARA REGISTRAR EN A BASE DE DATOS:**

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    $conexion=conexion();
    
    $jsondata = array();

    $celular=json_decode($_POST['celular']);
    $Parametro=json_decode($_POST['parametro']);
    $Cantidad=json_decode($_POST['cantIn']);
    $Preciounitario=json_decode($_POST['precio']);
    $SubTotal=json_decode($_POST['subtotal']);
    $Detrminacion=json_decode($_POST['determinacion']);
    $celular_val  = $celular[0];
    $cont=0;
    
 while( $cont < sizeof($Cantidad) )
{
    $consulta="INSERT INTO detallecotizacion (Num, Parametros, Cantidad, Determinacion, Preciounitario, Subtotal)
    VALUES ('$celular_val', '$Parametro[$cont]', '$Determinacion[$cont]', '$Cantidad[$cont]','$Preciounitario[$cont]', '$SubTotal[$cont]')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

        $cont=$cont+1;
    }
    return $result; 
?>
```

**MI ERROR:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ***¿QUE DEBERIA HACER? GRACIAS.***

Comment: Prueba quitándole el `processData:false,` y dime si al menos te has saltado ese error.

Answer (score 1):

prueba lo siguiente, quita los corchetes en la data del ajax asi :

```
$.ajax({
        url:'../Modelo/registrar_detallecot.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {celular: celular, parametro: parametro, cantIn: cantIn, precio :precio, subtotal :subtotal, determinacion:determinacion } ,
        //data: formData2,
        contentType: "json",
        processData:false,
        success: function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alertify.success("correcto Detalle!");

            }else{
                alertify.error("Fallo Detalle:(" + r);
                console.log(r);
            }
            setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000);
        }
    });
```

ya que si pones un corchetes estarías enviando un array de data y en php lo tendrás que recibir de diferente manera.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta pasar los datos sin que estén en arrays.
Por ejemplo, "aceites y grasas"|"físico químico"|120|1|120-"Alcalinidad total"|...

Después al llegar al PHP haz un explode por "-" así tendrás cada elemento por separado. Y luego un explode por "|" para tener cada valor por separado.